# How to start neo4j server from a given data path

Tags: neo4j

As the title says out loud.
How to start neo4j server with pure

```
$ neo4j start
```

I have trying to edit `dbms.directories.data` in the conf/neo4j.conf and it didn't work out.

I was using

```
 "neo4j_version" : "3.0.0"
```

Comment: Do you want to start neo4j with a specific data directory or do you only want to be able to type `neo4j start` to start neo4j?

Comment: I want to start neo4j with a specific data dir using `neo4j start`. I cannot see the real conflict here. The trick is to change the configuration, right?